# Django "request" object

Tags: django

I just started learning Django and Python a few weeks ago and have been tasked with a project to manage form processing using a Django/Python/MySQL combination.  My background is in C++, so if there are any C++ analogies in Python/Django syntax please feel free to reference them.

So far I understand what the HTTPRequest objects do, but can't understand this snippet of code:

```
@login_required(login_url="/some_directory/")
def xyz(request):
    item1 = request.GET['item1']
    user = request.user
    page = Page.objects.get(title = item1)
    item1info = {}
    perm_all = get_perms(user,page)
    item1info["industry"] = page.industry.split(',')
```

For the first line what does "@" do? Is "@login_required" a Django command or was was it defined by the coder already?

I know "def xyz(request)" defines a function, but is the parameter "request" something that's been pre-defined in another file (urls.py)?

What does request.GET['item1'] do? Is it retrieving the value of the element "item1" from the query string?

Comment: @login_required is a decorator. Decorators are a fundamental concept in python. I would suggest you read a python tutorial/book before trying to understand django.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- "@" is a [Decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/). [Login required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) is a decorator provided by Django that requires the current user (in request.user) to be logged in to visit this view.
- The "request" parameter is passed to the View function when its called, by Django itself. Any valid view function must receive the request as a paramete
- [Request.GET](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET) is a python dictionary that contains all the parameters passed in the request by GET method (as part of the URL querystring).

Comment: Where is the view function located? Is it in urls.py?

Comment: View functions are located on your app's directory, views.py.

Example: myapp/views.py